# Greek letters with legend

Tags: r

I'm trying to get Greek letters to appear in a legend command. I've tried all different ways to use "text" and "expression", but it doesn't work.  Here is the code.

```
plot(density(R1[,1,2]),ylim=c(0,1),
     xlab="Correlation",main="",lty=1)
lines(density(R2[,1,2]),lty=2)
lines(density(R3[,1,2]),lty=3)
legend("topright", title="Values for eta",lty=1:3,cex=.8,
       c("eta=1","eta=2","eta=3"))
```

Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: Depending on the application you can often use unicode for special characters. If you want uppercase eta \u0397 or lowercase \u03B7. eg. `legend("topright", title="Values for eta",lty=1:3,cex=.8,
       c("\u0397=1","\u03B7=2","\u03B7=3"))`

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass an expression vector for the labels. Character vectors are interpreted as literal text, which is not what you want.

We typically use `expression`, `str2expression`, or `parse` to construct expression vectors, depending on context. `expression` isn't vectorized, so it is less useful when programming but fine in simple cases like yours.

Here are three examples producing identical plots:

```r
plot(1:10
legend("topleft", legend = expression(paste(alpha, " = ", 1), paste(beta, " = ", 2), paste(gamma, " = ", 3)), lty = 1:3)

plot(1:10)
legend("topleft", legend = str2expression(paste(c("alpha", "beta", "gamma"), "* \" = \" *", 1:3)), lty = 1:3)

plot(1:10)
legend("topleft", legend = parse(text = paste(c("alpha", "beta", "gamma"), "* \" = \" *", 1:3)), lty = 1:3)
```

I would construct your labels like so:

```r
str2expression(paste("eta * \"=\" *", 1:3))
```

You'll find even more examples in `?plotmath` and the respective function help pages. `?plotmath` in particular documents the special syntax used by graphics devices to typeset labels given as expressions.